# No enabled local indexes to search

Tags: php, mysql, sphinx

I'm trying to set up my Sphinx3 search, I'm using the minimal default config file from
the distribution.

```
source src
{
    type            = mysql

    sql_host        = localhost
    sql_user        = a0239779_a*
    sql_pass        = r*
    sql_db          = a0239779_r*
    sql_port        = 3306  # optional, default is 3306
    
    sql_query       = \
        SELECT id, group_id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(date_added) AS date_added, title, content \
        FROM documents
    
    sql_attr_uint       = id
    sql_attr_timestamp  = date_added

}

index test1
{
    source          = src
    path            = /home/a0239779/sphinx/data/test1
}

index testrt
{
    type            = rt
    rt_mem_limit    = 128M

    path            = /home/a0239779/sphinx/data/testrt
    
    rt_field        = title
    rt_field        = content
    rt_attr_uint    = gid

}

indexer
{
    mem_limit       = 128M
}

searchd
{
    listen          = 9312
    listen          = 9306:mysql41
    log             = /home/a0239779/sphinx/log/searchd.log
    query_log       = /home/a0239779/sphinx/log/query.log
    read_timeout    = 5
    max_children    = 30
    pid_file        = /home/a0239779/sphinx/log/searchd.pid
    seamless_rotate = 1
    preopen_indexes = 1
    unlink_old      = 1
    workers         = threads # for RT to work
    binlog_path     = /home/a0239779/sphinx/data
}
```

I did the indexing, it seems allrght

```
[a0239779@jarl bin]$ indexer -c /home/a0239779/sphinx/etc/sphinx.conf --all
Sphinx 2.1.5-id64-release (rel21-r4508)
Copyright (c) 2001-2014, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2014, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/home/a0239779/sphinx/etc/sphinx.conf'...
indexing index 'test1'...
WARNING: attribute 'id' not found - IGNORING
collected 4 docs, 0.0 MB
sorted 0.0 Mhits, 100.0% done
total 4 docs, 227 bytes
total 0.013 sec, 17048 bytes/sec, 300.41 docs/sec
skipping non-plain index 'testrt'...
total 3 reads, 0.000 sec, 0.1 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 10 writes, 0.000 sec, 0.1 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
```

I made a start of the search, it seems allrght

```
[a0239779@jarl bin]$ ./sphinx.sh start
Sphinx 3.1.1 (commit 612d99f)
Copyright (c) 2001-2018, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2016, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/home/a0239779/sphinx/etc/sphinx.conf'...
listening on all interfaces, port=9312
listening on all interfaces, port=9306
precaching index 'test1'
WARNING: index 'test1': prealloc: /home/a0239779/sphinx/data/test1.sph is
v.38 (from Sphinx 2.x), binary is v.48; NOT SERVING
precaching index 'testrt'
precached 2 indexes in 0.001 sec
```

I checked the work of the search through the command, allrght

```
[a0239779@jarl bin\]$ search --config /home/a0239779/sphinx/etc/sphinx.conf 'another'
Sphinx 2.1.5-id64-release (rel21-r4508)
Copyright (c) 2001-2014, Andrew Aksyonoff
Copyright (c) 2008-2014, Sphinx Technologies Inc (http://sphinxsearch.com)

using config file '/home/a0239779/sphinx/etc/sphinx.conf'...
index 'test1': query 'another ': returned 1 matches of 1 total in 0.000 sec

displaying matches:

1. document=3, weight=2769, date_added=Sun Oct 11 19:25:17 2020

words:

1. 'another': 1 documents, 2 hits

index 'testrt': search error: failed to open /home/a0239779/sphinx/data/testrt.sph: 
No such file or directory.
```

Then I want to test direct SQL queries

mysql -h127.0.0.1 -P9306

```
mysql> SELECT * FROM test1 WHERE MATCH('another');
ERROR 1064 (42000): no enabled local indexes to search
```

Why is that?

Also I do show all tables

```
mysql> SHOW TABLES;
+--------+------+
| index | type |
+--------+------+
| testrt | rt |
+--------+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Why only 1 table? Where is my table "test1"

I am trying to test it via PHP

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1; port=9306; dbname=a0239779_r--; charset=utf8;",
"a0239779_a--", "a0239779_r--");
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$stmt = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `test1` WHERE MATCH('another')");
$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
var_dump($results);
```

**Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 no enabled
local indexes to search**

Should there be an index table test1 for SQL queries?

How can I use the RT table for SQL queries?

Answer (score 0):

The indexer did not create indexes because the old version 2.1.5 was launched when the command to index without absolute paths to the executable file and config

```
search --config /home/a0239779/sphinx/etc/sphinx.conf 'another'
Sphinx 2.1.5-id64-release (rel21-r4508)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
failed to open /home/a0239779/sphinx/data/testrt.sph: 
No such file or directory.
```

You should check if the directory  has write permissions (user and group).